# Appengine MemCache resets across multiple runs

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I m new to app engine. I m using Memcache and running it in eclipse. And every time i run the app the value of memcache resets. And i dont have the old values

```
MemcacheService memCache= MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
memCache.setErrorHandler(ErrorHandlers.getConsistentLogAndContinue(Level.INFO));
```

Comment: caches are always volatile. i couldn't understand, what're you tring to ask.

Comment: I thought Memcache is out-process cache which stores values irrespective of how many times i restart my application

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you are running the gae development environment locally starting it from inside Eclipse, then what are experiencing is expected behavior. The `memcached` instance gets started and stopped every time you restart the development environment. It is a memory only caching mechanism? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Is it possible to get previous value when i restart. Other wise it just looks like in-process cache

Comment: It is a memory only caching mechanism. But memcache uses memory of  a different machine.

Comment: what makes you think that? no matter you are wrong, the gae dev server runs on your machine with a memcached embedded inside it. read the docs on the dev server again.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So when i deploy it for production. Will it retain values across builds?

Comment: Yes, but remember items may be purged from memcache at any point, so you can't rely on memcache to hold any value.

Answer (score 0):

In GAE development-mode memcached is embedded into your process, so when your process terminates you loose your memcached instance as well.

However, when you deploy on your Goggle GAE account, the memcached instance is independent from your app. instance and cache values can survive your app instance restarts...but memcached instance itsself might be restarted by GAE and its not guaranteed to hold cache values for long time.

Also, you cannot use memcached as a system of record...since its not a persistent cache. If you want more reliable memcached implementation you can use [Couchbase](http://couchbase.com) that has clustered 24/7 memcached compatible implementation for enterprise level use. It can be used as system of record...e.g. its a "NoSQL DB" ... but its not offered in GAE.